# 'image_style' entity with ID 'media_library' already exists

Tags: 8, media

Recently updated Drupal to 8.7.1 and I am seeing the following error when running database update:

```
www-data@php.container:/var/www/html/web $ drush updb -y
The following updates are pending:

media_library module :
  8701 -   Create the 'media_library' image style.
  8702 -   Updates the media library view widget display (contextual) filters.

comment module :
  Add comment settings.

media_library module :
  Create and configure Media Library form and view displays for media types.
  Add a table display to the media library view and link gridtable displays.

media module :
  Keep media items viewable at media{id}.

menu_link_content module :
  Update custom menu links to be revisionable.

system module :
  Initialize 'expand_all_items' values to system_menu_block.
  Clear the menu cache.   @see https:www.drupal.orgprojectdrupalissues3044364

taxonomy module :
  Update taxonomy terms to be revisionable.
  Remove the 'hierarchy' property from vocabularies.

views module :
  Update exposed filter blocks label display to be disabled.
  Rebuild cache to allow placeholder texts to be translatable.

Do you wish to run all pending updates? (y/n): y
'image_style' entity with ID 'media_library' already exists.                                          [error]
Performing media_library_update_8701                                                                     [ok]
Failed: 'image_style' entity with ID 'media_library' already exists.                                  [error]
Cache rebuild complete.                                                                                  [ok]
Finished performing updates.                                                                             [ok]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by doing the following:

Removing the media_libary (I'm using git but if not you can move it somewhere):

```
rm image.style.media_library.yml
rm views.view.media_library.yml
```

Run configuration import:

```
drush cim -y
```

Now run database update:

```
drush updb -y
```

Now add the removed config items back in:

```
git checkout ./
```

Run configuration import again:

```
drush cim -y
```

Now you should be all set.